# Brush tool line very faint when using click, shift+click to draw straight lines

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I'm trying to draw straight lines in photoshop with my Wacom tablet, and the lines are coming up very faint and short. Is there a way to lengthen the lines created by the click, shift+click method?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your brush settings for this. If you use it frequently it might be worth creating a preset for yourself. Turn off Transfer and put Opacity and Fill to 100%.